# window.open() in JavaScript is not working in Chrome responsive mode

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm trying to use window.open() to open external link in new tab in Chrome. It is working fine. But the issue is when I switch to Chrome responsive mode and setting resolution to 1280X780px, the redirection to external site is not happening.

What kind of workaround could I use here?

Comment: cannot reproduce it, its working here. which version of chrome are you using?

Comment: Kindly share logs if any